# Нігти зрізають чи стрижуть?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова

СУМ-11

> [Зрізати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zrizuvaty)1. Ріжучи, відокремлювати що-небудь від чогось (перев.
>   верхню частину).
>
> [Стригти](http://sum.in.ua/s/stryghty)1. перех. і без додатка. Ножицями, машинкою і т. ін.
>   зрізувати, підрізувати (волосся, шерсть і т. ін.).

Як правильно казати та писати стригти чи зрізати нігті?

Comment: а ще обскубують та обтенькують

Answer (score 2):

Нігті можна "обстригати" або ж "підрізати". Дивимось в СУМі визначення слова "[обстригати](http://sum.in.ua/s/obstryghaty)":

> //  Обрізаючи або підрізаючи ножицями, машинкою і т. ін. волосся,
> вовну, **нігті**, вкорочувати їх. З-під рук у батька вхопила [Тоня]
> його чабанські ножиці і вже замахнулась ними обстригати, вкорочувати
> свої вії (Олесь Гончар, Тронка, 1963, 65); Веліла [панія].. дівчинці
> косу обстригти... (Данило Мордовець, I, 1958, 145).

Гадаю, що також можливий варіант "стригти нігті" (у слова "стригти" є значення "підрізувати", "вкорочувати", а також такий віріант є досить розповсюдженим в Інтернеті).

Answer (score 1):

Не бачу ніяких перепон для застосування будь-якого з цих слів до нігтів:

- ***стригти***:

  > Існує побутовий вираз, який красномовно засвідчує різницю між українцями як титульною нацією і українцями як національною меншиною: «коли в Москві стрижуть нігті, у Харкові (Києві) відрубують пальці». //Станіслав Кульчицький
  >
  > Ще й доводиться мити тих, хто сам не може, годувати поранених з ложечки, голити, стригти нігті, обробляти ранки, втирати антигрибкові мазі між пальцями ніг (на передовій іноді впродовж кількох діб не знімають берців)… //Галина Вдовиченко
  >
  > Натомість, були: номер з подряпаною шісткою, що впадав у вічі одразу з перехрестя, від якого залишалось пройти рівно тридцять сім кроків до третього під'їзду; стара покручена абрикоса; голе вікно, де ніколи не вішали фіранок, і тому в його жовтому беззубому роті можна було часто вгледіти, як сусідка стриже нігті, або варить їсти, або плаче; а ще — лавка, повна за будь-якої погоди балакучих бабусь, і квітничок з дохлякуватими айстрами, і прорізаний до кісток у тілі вхідних дверей напис «Лідка-інвалідка», і цей особливий запах супу та вологої собачої шерсті на першому поверсі, і щербатий вишкір третьої сходинки другого прольоту, і чорний візерунчастий дерматин на дверях, і продавлена пипка власного дзвоника… //Ірина Цілик
- ***зрізати***:

  > Спочатку заявив, що хоче поголити бороду, потім захотів помити голову, а потім йому заманулося зрізати нігті на ногах, бо вони, мовляв, дуже відросли. //Анатолій Іллічевський (перекладаючи Джанні Родарі)
  >
  > Недарма ж тоді казали: якщо в Москві зрізають нігті, то в Україні рубають пальці. //Валентин Чемерис
  >
  > — Ми стежимо тільки за тим, щоб йому зрізали нігті. //Леонід Кононович (перекладаючи Жана-Крістофа Ґранже).

Так само, як і варіантів *обстригати* й *підрізати*, [зазначених Анатолієм у відповіді](/a/5266).

Семантична різниця полягає в такому:

- *стригти*, наскільки я можу судити, акцентує підрізання/зрізання декількох однотипних елементів. Якщо ви підрізаєте/зрізаєте лише один ніготь, то це навряд можна назвати *стригти* (хіба що: маючи на увазі, що Ви проконтролювали довжину всіх, але реально вкорочувати довелося лише один) — але зазвичай люди підрізають/зрізають відразу всі нігті.
- *підріз(ув)ати* робить акцент на невеличкому зменшенні розміру нігтя. Якщо Ви багато років відрощували нігті довжиною понад 10 см, а потім раптово позбулися їх, то це навряд можна назвати *підріз(ув)ати* (хіба що жартома) — але зазвичай люди не відрощують нігті такої довжини, тому зменшування розмірів справді відбувається незначне.
- *зріз(ув)ати* робить акцент на відокремленні нігтя. Формально кажучи, *зрізати ніготь* можна зрозуміти як повне зрізання всієї нігтьової пластини — але не практиці люди розуміють, що під *зрізанням нігтя* мається на увазі зрізання лише зайвої частини, тому зазвичай непорозумінь не виникає.
- в чому семантична різниця *обстригати* й *стригти*, я поки не зрозумів.

(Див. також [цю мою відповідь](/q/5264).)